# Calculating the sum of select statement value group by specific ID

Tags: mysql

My questiong is very simple.....

I just want to calculate the total of room_1_price where hotel_id is the same.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/575d3/92

Here I want to calculate the ROOM_1_PRICE GROUP BY HOTEL_ID which means ROOM_1_SUM must be 170 where HOTEL_ID is 1 because HOTEL_ID 1 is common in 3 rows.

Many thanks in advance, 
Anna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my answer is much more simplier http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/575d3/114

Comment: I really thanks for your huge support.. I was trying to fix it up since a long time.. but you really did it... I really appreciate your way..

Comment: Can i ask u you another thing.. For calculating the another which room_2_price... Should i duplicate the same ways of subselect query of room_1_sum??